# Populating select menus + dynamic menu adding - HTML/Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Warning: I am new to HTML, JS and using Jquery in general, so please don't be too brutal :)

Right now I need to have three side by side drop down menus which represent system configurations. I need these menus to be added added dynamically (which I have been able to do) and also have the contents of the OS field be populated based on what the user selects for the issp version.

I have been able to get these things to work on their own, but not in tandem which leads me to believe that it has something to do with the divs. Here's what I am working with. Should also note this is my first time on stack overflow, so if I'm including too much code here, just let me know and I can reduce.

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



var issp_34 = [
    {display: "OSX 10.6.2", value: "osx_10.6.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.7.4", value: "osx_10.7.4"},
    {display: "OSX 10.8.2", value: "osx_10.8.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.9.2", value: "osx_10.9.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.10", value: "osx_10.10"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.3", value: "rhel_5.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.4", value: "rhel_5.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.5", value: "rhel_5.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.6", value: "rhel_5.6"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.7", value: "rhel_5.7"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.8", value: "rhel_5.8"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.9", value: "rhel_5.9"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.10", value: "rhel_5.10"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.11", value: "rhel_5.11"},
    {display: "RHEL 6", value: "rhel_6"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.1", value: "rhel_6.1"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.2", value: "rhel_6.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.3", value: "rhel_6.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.4", value: "rhel_6.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.5", value: "rhel_6.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.6", value: "rhel_6.6"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp3", value: "sles10_sp3"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp4", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 11", value: "sles11"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp1", value: "sles11_sp1"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp2", value: "sles11_sp2"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp3", value: "sles11_sp3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u3", value: "rhel_4_u3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u7", value: "rhel_4_u7"}];

var issp_32 = [
    {display: "OSX 10.6.2", value: "osx_10.6.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.7.4", value: "osx_10.7.4"},
    {display: "OSX 10.8.2", value: "osx_10.8.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.9.2", value: "osx_10.9.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.3", value: "rhel_5.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.4", value: "rhel_5.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.5", value: "rhel_5.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.6", value: "rhel_5.6"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.7", value: "rhel_5.7"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.8", value: "rhel_5.8"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.9", value: "rhel_5.9"},
    {display: "RHEL 6", value: "rhel_6"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.1", value: "rhel_6.1"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.2", value: "rhel_6.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.3", value: "rhel_6.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.4", value: "rhel_6.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.5", value: "rhel_6.5"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp3", value: "sles10_sp3"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp4", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 11", value: "sles11"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp1", value: "sles11_sp1"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp2", value: "sles11_sp2"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp3", value: "sles11_sp3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u3", value: "rhel4_u3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u7", value: "rhel4_u7"}];

var issp_31 = [
    {display: "OSX 10.6.2", value: "osx_10.6.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.7.4", value: "osx_10.7.4"},
    {display: "OSX 10.8.2", value: "osx_10.8.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.3", value: "rhel_5.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.4", value: "rhel_5.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.5", value: "rhel_5.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.6", value: "rhel_5.6"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.7", value: "rhel_5.7"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.8", value: "rhel_5.8"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.9", value: "rhel_5.9"},
    {display: "RHEL 6", value: "rhel_6"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.1", value: "rhel_6.1"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.2", value: "rhel_6.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.3", value: "rhel_6.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.4", value: "rhel_6.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.5", value: "rhel_6.5"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp3", value: "sles10_sp3"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp4", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 11", value: "sles11"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp1", value: "sles11_sp1"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp2", value: "sles11_sp2"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp3", value: "sles11_sp3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u3", value: "rhel4_u3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u7", value: "rhel4_u7"}];

var issp_30 = [
    {display: "OSX 10.6.2", value: "osx_10.6.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.7.4", value: "osx_10.7.4"},
    {display: "OSX 10.8.2", value: "osx_10.8.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.3", value: "rhel_5.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.4", value: "rhel_5.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.5", value: "rhel_5.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.6", value: "rhel_5.6"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.7", value: "rhel_5.7"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.8", value: "rhel_5.8"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.9", value: "rhel_5.9"},
    {display: "RHEL 6", value: "rhel_6"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.1", value: "rhel_6.1"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.2", value: "rhel_6.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.3", value: "rhel_6.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.4", value: "rhel_6.4"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp3", value: "sles10_sp3"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp4", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 11", value: "sles11"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp1", value: "sles11_sp1"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp2", value: "sles11_sp2"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u3", value: "rhel4_u3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u7", value: "rhel4_u7"}];

var issp_26 = [
    {display: "OSX 10.5.8", value: "osx_10.5.8"},
    {display: "OSX 10.6.2", value: "osx_10.6.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.7.4", value: "osx_10.7.4"},
    {display: "OSX 10.8.2", value: "osx_10.8.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.10", value: "osx_10.10"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.3", value: "rhel_5.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.4", value: "rhel_5.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.5", value: "rhel_5.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.6", value: "rhel_5.6"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.7", value: "rhel_5.7"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.8", value: "rhel_5.8"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.9", value: "rhel_5.9"},
    {display: "RHEL 6", value: "rhel_6"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.1", value: "rhel_6.1"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.2", value: "rhel_6.2"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.3", value: "rhel_6.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.4", value: "rhel_6.4"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp2", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp3", value: "sles10_sp3"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp4", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 11", value: "sles11"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp1", value: "sles11_sp1"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp2", value: "sles11_sp2"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u3", value: "rhel4_u3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u7", value: "rhel4_u7"}];

var issp_25 = [
    {display: "OSX 10.5.8", value: "osx_10.5.8"},
    {display: "OSX 10.6.2", value: "osx_10.6.2"},
    {display: "OSX 10.10", value: "osx_10.10"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.3", value: "rhel_5.3"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.4", value: "rhel_5.4"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.5", value: "rhel_5.5"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.6", value: "rhel_5.6"},
    {display: "RHEL 5.7", value: "rhel_5.7"},
    {display: "RHEL 6", value: "rhel_6"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.1", value: "rhel_6.1"},
    {display: "RHEL 6.2", value: "rhel_6.2"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp2", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp3", value: "sles10_sp3"},
    {display: "SLES 10 sp4", value: "sles10_sp4"},
    {display: "SLES 11", value: "sles11"},
    {display: "SLES 11 sp1", value: "sles11_sp1"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u3", value: "rhel4_u3"},
    {display: "RHEL 4 u7", value: "rhel4_u7"}];

    
$("#issp_version").change(function() {
        var parent = $(this).val(); 
        window.alert("ASD");
        switch(parent){ 
              case 'issp_3.3':
                list(issp_33);
                break;
              case 'issp_3.2':
                list(issp_32);
                break;              
              case 'issp_3.1':
                list(issp_31);
                break;  
              case 'issp_3.0':
                list(issp_30);
                break; 
              case 'issp_2.6':
                list(issp_26);
                break; 
              case 'issp_2.5':
                list(issp_25);
                break; 
            default: 
                $("#os_selection").html('');  
                break;
           }
});

    
   
function list(array_list) {
    window.alert("ASD");
    $("#os_selection").html(""); 
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { 
        $("#os_selection").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
    });
}
    

function addSelect(divname, container) {
   var newDiv=document.createElement('div'); 
   var numDivs=$("#container div").length-1;
   newDiv.id = 'node' + numDivs;
   var html='<select name="node_type" id="node_type">';
   html+='<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Node Type</option>';
   html+='<option value="con">CON</option>';
   html+='<option value="scn">SCN</option>';
   html+='<option value="mds">MDS</option>';
   html+='</select>';
   html+='<select name="issp_version" id="issp_version">';
   html+='<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">ISSP/CXFS Version</option>';
   html+='<option value="stout7">stout7/cxfs-Dev</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_3.4">ISSP 3.4/CXFS 7.4</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_3.3">ISSP 3.3/CXFS 7.3</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_3.2">ISSP 3.2/CXFS 7.2</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_3.1">ISSP 3.1//CXFS 7.1</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_3.0">ISSP 3.0/CXFS 7.0</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_2.6">ISSP 2.6/CXFS 6.6</option>';
   html+='<option value="issp_2.5">ISSP 2.5/CXFS 6.5</option>';
   html+='</select>';
   html+='<select name="os_selection" id="os_selection">';
   html+='<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Operating System</option>';
   html += '</select><br></br>';
   newDiv.innerHTML= html;
   document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv);
}



</script>
```

```html
<body><b>Virtual Cluster Initialization</b><br></br>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="general">
  <form>Cluster name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="cluster_name">
  <br>
  Host Machine:<br>
  <input type="text" name="host_machine"> 
  </form>
 </div>
 <div id="nodes"></div>
 <button id="add" onclick="addSelect('nodes','container');">+</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Where is the html for `#issp_version`? Also please read [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and there [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); for instance all your arrays `var issp_32 = [ ....` could contain only a few values to demonstrate what you are looking for. It seems that `addSelect()` is never called. If you create a sample (jsfiddle, plunkr, codepen) it is easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyze your code the problem is

```
$("#issp_version").change() function
```

Because you are assigning the function definition to an element, but this element doesn't exist yet.
you could add the function **$("#issp_version").change()** into *addSelect* function
But when you are adding new VM(do click more than once in add Button) the **Id=os_selection** doesn't be unique, so you need to front this Issue in other way

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers. I ended up giving each os_selection a unique ID and then rewrote the `$("#issp_version").change() function` into a regular function that would be called by the addition of an onchange=callFunction to each issp_version select.